# Cpanel Cron job not executing code in .php file

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I need to run a specific url on my domain

> http://domain.com/?action=update_feed

, so I made a cron-file.php file, which contains the below code:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://domain.com/?action=update_feed"); /* Redirect browser */
exit;
?>
```

In Cpanel's cron manager, i added this to run each minute:

php -q /home/public_html/domain/wp-content/themes/theme/cron-file.php

However, nothing is happening. I also tried using wget instead of php but get the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly access you site without cron-file.php

```
    wget -qO /dev/null 'http://domain.com/?action=update_feed'
```